# Wireless keyboard key writes wrong character when greater-than / less-than key is pressed in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Wireless keyboard key writes wrong character when greater-than / less-than key is pressed in Ubuntu, but works fine when pressed while on Windows (I have a dual boot setup on my laptop).

The wireless keyboard in question is the Logitech K235 that you can see here:

[image]

As you can see, it is the spanish version. It has a greater-than / less-than key between the left shift key and the Z.

In Ubuntu, that key writes the backslash (\) and with shift it writes the vertical bar (|).

No change when combining with AltGr: when pressing with AltGr, it writes the backslash (\) and when pressing AltGr+Shift+(that key) it writes the vertical bar (|).

In Windows it writes the < > characters just fine. The less-than (<) character with just that key, and the greater-than (>) with shift.

My laptop is the Lenovo Thinkpad T480. I run Windows 10 and Ubuntu MATE 18.04.3, both installed from recently downloaded images and updated.

The keyboard layout in both Windows and Ubuntu is set to spanish. Here is the screenshot of Ubuntu MATE's keyboard layout:

[image]

I have used this keyboard for at least two years with another laptop and that key worked fine on both Windows and Ubuntu with this same setup.

What can I do to get that key to write the < > characters in Ubuntu?

Right now if I want those characters, I have to do AltGr+Shift+Z for the < and AltGr+Shift+X for the > , and if that's the case I just stop using this keyboard and use the laptop's keyboard (that has the US english layout so kind of annoying when trying to write correctly in spanish).

I do a lot of web development in Ubuntu so using this keyboard was perfect to write correctly in spanish while having that key available for PHP/HTML where you use it constantly.

Thanks in advance for any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar situation here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1075300/620814

OP found that if you put the Spanish layout first in the list of layouts in "Keyboard Preferences" > "General" the key works as expected.

I don't understand the logic either but that workaround also works for me.